# Get the type of an Object which is a property of another object

Tags: .net, reflection

For pupose of explaining let's say that I have a Company object which has an Address property of type Address. so it would be something like:

```
public class Company  
{  
    Address CompanyAddress;
}  

public class Address  
{
    int Number;
    string StreetName;  
}
```

Now I have a method that works with any kind of object type and I want to get a specific property from the received object, so I'm trying the following:

```
public string MyMethod(object myObject, string propertyName)
{
    Type objectType = myObject.GetType();
    object internalObject = objectType.GetProperty("Address");

    Type internalType = internalObject.GetType();
    PropertyInfo singleProperty = internalType.GetProperty("StreetName");

    return singleProperty.GetValue(internalObject, null).ToString();
}
```

The problem is that internalType is never Address but "System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo" so singleProperty is always null;

How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `internalObject` will be the `PropertyInfo` object returned by `GetProperty` method. You need to get the actual value of that property, hence the call to `GetValue` method.

```
public string MyMethod(object myObject, string propertyName) {
    Type objectType = myObject.GetType();
    object internalObject = objectType.GetProperty("Address").GetValue(myObject, null);

    Type internalType = internalObject.GetType();
    PropertyInfo singleProperty = internalType.GetProperty("StreetName");

    return singleProperty.GetValue(internalObject, null).ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The internalObject is just a PropertyInfo object, just like singleProperty is.

You should use the same technique to extract the actual object:

```
    PropertyInfo addressProperty = objectType.GetProperty("Address");

    object interalObject = addressProperty.GetValue(myObject);
```

The rest is correct.